# Spring Integration gateway error channel - no such bean exception

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration, gateway

I've configured a spring integration gateway with a service activator backed by a threadpool.
Everything works fine, till I try to add my own error channel.
Spring begins to complain that it cannot find a bean by the name of the error channel.

Here is my xml config:

```
    <int:gateway service-interface="Messaging.SendMessageToDeviceGateWay"
        error-channel="send_message_to_device_error_channel"
        default-request-channel="send_message_to_device_channel" 
        id="send_message_to_device_gateway">

        </int:gateway>

    <int:channel id="send_message_to_device_channel">
        <int:queue message-store="redisMessageStore" />
    </int:channel>

    <bean id="sendMessageToDeviceServiceBeanId" class="Messaging.SendMessageToDeviceService" />

    <int:service-activator input-channel="send_message_to_device_channel"
        ref="sendMessageToDeviceServiceBeanId" method="send_message">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="500" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"
            task-executor="send_message_to_device_task_executor" receive-timeout="0" />
    </int:service-activator>


    <bean id="sendMessageToDeviceErrorHandlerBeanId" 
        class="Messaging.SendMessageToDeviceErrorHandler" />



    <int:service-activator input-channel = "send_message_to_device_error_channel"
        ref="sendMessageToDeviceErrorHandlerBeanId" method="handle_error">
    </int:service-activator>
```

The error I am seeing is :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'send_message_to_device_gateway': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'send_message_to_device_error_channel' while setting bean property 'errorChannel'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'send_message_to_device_error_channel' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'send_message_to_device_error_channel' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:694)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
... 37 more
```

Why is it looking for a bean by that name?

Thanks in advance,
Richard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct: any bean must be presented in the application context.

Even if you use a default `errorChannel`, it is populated to the application context by the Spring Integration infrastructure.

So, you must provide `<channel id="send_message_to_device_error_channel"/>` anyway.

Comment: Hi, I did as you said, and that error vanished, but given the same configuration that I have pasted above, the error is not being received on my error handler. Any ideas on what may be the cause? Its still going to the default error logging handler. @Artem Bilan

Comment: Your error might not be received on the gateway's error-channel, because you use `<queue>` channel downstream. Try to add your `send_message_to_device_error_channel` on the `<poller>`.

Comment: I must say you are very well versed in Spring Integration,and your answers are spot-on, my only problem is , that none of this is explicitly mentioned in the Spring Integration docs. They mention that the error channel will only catch errors from the thread pool executor, but not that the error channel should be placed on the poller, although that makes perfect sense. Could you point me to a place where I can find some examples of such configurations? Thanks again, @Artem Bilan.

Comment: See here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#endpoint-namespace. However I agree the docs are weak. Feel free to raise a JIRA(https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) and we'll take care on the matter in the chapter: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-adapter. Re. me: please, read an author list on the first page of the SI Manual :-)

Comment: woah! didn't know I was talking to the author himself, thanks again, I'll open a issue soon.